# GPIO output initially on and GPIO.output

Tags: python, gpio

I'm new to python and am attempting to control solenoid valves using a relay, RPi, PIR sensor and python script. [I found a script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NMTlqZguVYYVp1T1NGM0tHa28/view) posted online I used as a base and modified it a bit to switch my relay. Everything seems to be working as expected overall, but I've noticed the following:

- As soon as I run the script in terminal, the relay switches are on. After first trigger , they will stay off until the following trigger. Why are they intially on?
- In my code I'm using `GPIO.output(<variable>,False)` to switch **on** and `GPIO.output(<variable>,True)` to turn **off** which seems backward. Shouldn't the False argument turn the switch off and True turn on?

Code below. Any pointers or insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
# Import required Python libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import random

# Use BCM GPIO references
# instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define GPIO to use on Pi
pir = 17
arm_one = 23
arm_two = 24

print "PIR Module Test (CTRL-C to exit)"

# Set pin as input
GPIO.setup(pir,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(arm_one,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(arm_two,GPIO.OUT)


current_state  = 0
previous_state = 0

def getRandomNum():
    random_sleep=random.uniform(0,1)
    return random_sleep;

try:

  print "Waiting for PIR to settle ..."

  # Loop until PIR output is 0
  while GPIO.input(pir)==1:
    current_state  = 0

  print "  Ready"

  # Loop until users quits with CTRL-C
  while True:

    # Read PIR state
    current_state = GPIO.input(pir)

    if current_state==1 and previous_state==0:
      # PIR is triggered
      print "  Motion detected!"
      for i in range(5):
          GPIO.output(arm_one,False)
          GPIO.output(arm_two,False)
          time.sleep(1)
          GPIO.output(arm_one,True)
          time.sleep(getRandomNum())
          GPIO.output(arm_two,True)
          time.sleep(getRandomNum())
          GPIO.output(arm_one,False)
          time.sleep(getRandomNum())
          GPIO.output(arm_one,True)
          GPIO.output(arm_two,False)
          time.sleep(getRandomNum())
          GPIO.output(arm_two,True)

      # Record previous state
      previous_state=1
    elif current_state==0 and previous_state==1:
      # PIR has returned to ready state
      print "  Ready"
      GPIO.output(arm_one,True)
      GPIO.output(arm_two,True)
      previous_state=0

    # Wait for 10 milliseconds
    time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that sensor, but if it is wired up backwards (power on ground/ground on power for instance), it "might" explain the backwards behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LaneL! I can see that happening, but I would assume if it we're something like you say, then the relay would be on an "on" state the whole time the pi was powered on. However as soon as I run the script in terminal, it switches to on. So I'm just assuming its the code